# forward declaration of global friend function

Tags: c++, qt, friend, forward-declaration

I have the following namespaces and classes hierarchy:

```
namespace Ns1 {
    class Outer {
    private:
           class Inner {
           };
           QSet<Inner> set;
    };
}
```

Now I need to declare a global functions:

```
uint qHash(Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el);
bool operator==(Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el1,
                Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el);
```

So the function must be a friend to Outer and Inner.
The problem and to show that the function is in global scope:

```
friend uint qHash(Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el);
friend operator==(Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el1,
                Ns1::Outer::Inner const& el);
```

I can't deal with forward declarations for this case. Any solutions?

Comment: Why this function needs to be a "global" function? I think the problem is here itself. If the argument it can accepts is `Ns1::Outer::Inner` then I don't see any point in making the function outside the namespace `Ns1`. I also don't see any point in making it a non-member function given that `Inner` is `private` to `Outer`.

Comment: Plz. The problem is the problem that I stated. Don't make ur personal assumptions. Give the solution if it exists.

Comment: How do you want to get an `Inner` object to pass it to the function, if `Inner` is private? This looks loke a design issue - like many uses of `friend`. And no, you don't need `f` to be a friend of `Inner` - unless it uses private/protected methods of it.

Comment: @user14416: The solution may not exist because YOU are making the wrong personal assumptions.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you provided a combined example with the `friend` declaration in context. And is that also the definition? And why does it need to be declared in namespace scope, when it's already found by ADL and part of a large overload set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

You're right! You've found a corner case that the language just can't handle (because `friend`ship declarations only apply to previously declared functions or else to the innermost namespace). Unfortunately this means you're going to have to slightly restructure your code, as what you want to do can't be done in exactly that way.

The simplest approach is to define the two functions in the `Ns1` namespace and then `using` them into the global namespace. This has basically the exact same effect as what you want except there are two extra functions in the nested namespace.

Your other set of options involves addressing the problem at its root: Why do your class objects' public interface not provide an adequate capability such that friendship is needed? For example, why is `Inner` private within `Outer` if you're intended to be able to pass around `Inner` objects at global scope?

Why do hash and compare functions need access to `Inner`'s internal state? Why not have `Inner` provide a public comparison interface that's then utilized by the operators?

Comment: Actually that doesn't solve it because apparently the functions need to already be declared if you qualify them with ::. And you can't forward-declare them because their signatures need the complete definition of Outer. Seems like a language flaw.